# Set-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\[App_Pool] -Name Recycling.PeriodicRestart.Time has no effect in Server 2012 R2

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I've got a couple of farms of servers, one with `Server 2008 R2` and one with `Server 2012 R2`.  After a bunch of searching, I found the following powershell to disable default IIS application pool recycling, which I run at an administrative powershell prompt:

```
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\Test -Name Recycling.PeriodicRestart.Time -Value 0
```

This seems to work fine (it runs without any output on either platform), but when I subsequently attempt to query the value, on `Server 2008 R2`, I get this:

```
PSPath                      : WebAdministration::\\SERVER1\AppPools\Test
PSParentPath                : WebAdministration::\\SERVER1\AppPools
PSChildName                 : Test
PSDrive                     : IIS
PSProvider                  : WebAdministration
IsInheritedFromDefaultValue : False
IsProtected                 : False
Name                        : time
TypeName                    : System.TimeSpan
Schema                      : Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationAttributeSchema
Value                       : 00:00:00
IsExtended                  : False
```

but on `Server 2012 R2`, I get this:

```
PSPath                      : WebAdministration::\\SERVER2\AppPools\Test
PSParentPath                : WebAdministration::\\SERVER2\AppPools
PSChildName                 : Test
PSDrive                     : IIS
PSProvider                  : WebAdministration
IsInheritedFromDefaultValue : True
IsProtected                 : False
Name                        : time
TypeName                    : System.TimeSpan
Schema                      : Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationAttributeSchema
Value                       : 1.05:00:00
IsExtended                  : False
```

Notice that the `Value` in the first example is `00:00:00`, but in the second example is `1.05:00:00`. This is the default value inherited from the `DefaultAppPool`.

I've attempted to change the value for `DefaultAppPool` as well, but I get the same results--it works on `2008 R2` but not on `2012 R2`, so I'm fairly certain that inheritance isn't the issue.

Is there some alternate way to do this in `Server 2012 R2` so that it doesn't ignore the command or better yet--a way to do it that works in both `Server 2008 R2` and `Server 2012 R2`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ugh.  After much frustration, it appears that `Set-ItemProperty`is [case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169887/why-get-itemproperty-is-case-insensitive-but-set-itemproperty-is-case-sensitive), even though `Get-ItemProperty` is not.  To all who find this, the solution is quite simple:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "IIS:\AppPools\Test" -Name recycling.periodicRestart.time -Value 00:00:00
```

(notice the lower-casing on the property name).  To add insult to injury in `Server 2012 R2`, `Set-ItemProperty` fails silently in the case (no pun intended) where the property name casing doesn't exactly match the proper XML element names in the underlying `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` file.

Comment: Nice find, this one's real mean. Additionally we noticed in our team that case-sensitivity also depends on the PowerShell version. In 5.0 `Set-Item` didn't care about case, in `5.1` it does.

Comment: Or it depends on the IIS version. IIS 7.5 ignores case. IIS 10 does not.